# JavaScript form submits, but post data not available in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit

It seems the form submits (to the same page - `contact.php`), but I can not use posted data, for example `$_POST["message"]` . seems they are empty (I tried to echo them and nothing printed out).

This is JavaScript (in head section of page):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#contactform').submit(function(){
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post("contact.php", {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            company: $('#company').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        }, function(data,status){
            alert("status = " + status);            
            $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
            if(data=='Message sent!') $('#contactform').slideUp();
           });
           return false;
    });
});
```

this is form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
  <ol>
     <li>
        <label for="name">First Name <a href="#">*</a></label>
        <input name="name" id="name" class="text">
     </li>
     <li>
        <label for="email">Your e-mail <a href="#">*</a></label>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="text">
     </li>
     <li>
        <label for="company">Company Name</label>
        <input id="company" name="company" class="text">
     </li>
     <li>
        <label for="subject">Subject<br>
        </label>
        <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text">
     </li>
     <li>
        <label for="message">Message <a href="#">*</a></label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
     </li>
     <li class="buttons">
        <input type="image" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" src="images/but_send_message.gif">
     </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

The `alert("status = " + status);` section on javascript pops up the status as `sucess`.

**UPDATED**

And this is PHP part at the top of contact.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["message"])){
    echo '<script>alert("some dummy text");</script>';
  };
?>
```

It is not just that echo does not print anything, but I can not access values from posted data. PHPMailer works fine with manually assigned text to parameters.

Comment: You'll have to post the PHP as well. Where are you echoing the POST variables, and where are you expecting them to print out?

Comment: It seems fine, can you try `$('#contactform').serialize()`, anyway ?

Comment: And in the Form, there is no submit button. How can you submit the form?

Comment: No need to ask, put the php code to check.

Comment: @Akilan - input type image is valid, and will submit the form.

Comment: You realize that nothing will be outputted to the page when you use ajax, the echo'ed string is returned to the ajax function ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera, I will give it a try and report the results. thanks

Comment: @Akilan, There is a new type of submit button that is image, google it

Comment: @SheikhHeera, Your answer works! please post your answer so that I can accept it. but whats wrong with submit? and another question: what is the best way to detect the page has posted data instead of `isset($_POST['message'])`?

Comment: @Arash: please try what i mentioned in my answer. you will get the output

Comment: @Akilan `inputs` have value like `textarea` s. there is no difference in this manner Akilan. Are you sure this is the source of conflict?

Comment: @Arash - It's not, `val()` is just fine, and `serialize()` does whatever it is you're trying to do yourself by building the object.

Comment: @arash: 100% yes. I faced the same problem previously in my code. Just try it and give your response. If i am wrong, i will accept it

Comment: @Akilan - You're wrong, and I'll gladly prove it -> http://jsfiddle.net/8JNuP/

Comment: @Akilan I was sure, but as your suggestion I did the trick, but it did not solve the problem. I am really sorry!

Comment: @Arash, posted the answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Sheikh heera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741747/sheikh-heera) mentioned in his comment on my question, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#contactform').serialize(function(){
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post("contact.php", {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            company: $('#company').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        }, function(data,status){
                $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
                if(data=='Message sent!') $('#contactform').slideUp();
          });
          return false;
    });
});
```

and it works fine now! thanks to other users that suggested alternate solutions which may be working on this case but as I found the solution, there is no need to check them.

Answer (score 1):

If $_POST returns empty data. Make sure that you don't have any htaccess causing this.
I had this problem once. My htaccess always emptied the post data. After modifying the htaccess I got my problem solved.

Comment: There is no htaccess mismatch, as I tried out the solution presented by Sheikh Heera and it works fine! but thank you anyway for you useful information (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code to post the form and check will getting $_POST on contact.php or not

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#submitbtn").click(function(){
        $("#contactform").attr("action" , "contact.php");
        $("#contactform").submit();


});

</script>
```

If in contact.php if you get $_POST then show success message

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["message"])){
    echo '<script>alert("some dummy text");</script>';
  };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your post values in a variable. For example:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

You can echo this variable in your script:

```
var name ="<?php echo $name; ?>";
```

Comment: I need to first check if `$_POST["name"]` is set using `isset($_POST["name"])` and that returns false. are you sure there is yet chance for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following:
1) provide an id or a class to the li class button's child's input tag

2) Then in jquery write a code to handle :

```
$('.inputButton').click(function(){
    var data = $('#contactform').serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(key, field) {
        // Perform your validations over the data here
        console.log('field Name == '+field.name+', field value == '+field.value);
    });


    // Make an ajax call using this data
    $.post("contact.php", data, function(returnData) {
        // Handle your code for after form submission response
    });
});
```

3) Then in PHP you can get values as :

```
$name = $_POST["name"]; // and so on...
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem

Comment: I realize that this is so close to the solution I suggested, but what is the need to have so many things on jquery to manipulate the submit action on a form?!!1

Comment: If user defined validations is required then this can be one of the better cases for client side validation, where the user can validate every data before submitting the page